# Run remote Powershell session as version 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm on a server that is running Powershell Version 2:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name      Value
----      -----
...
PSVersion 2.0
```

I then create a new remote session to a different computer and connect to it:

```
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName {ComputerName} -Credential $credential
```

It returns me the result:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock { $PSVersionTable }

Name      Value
----      -----
...
PSVersion 3.0
```

However, I need Powershell to be in Version 2 for my script so I enter a session (to make it easier). I then try to get Powershell to be Version 2:

```
C:\> Enter-PSSession -Session $sess
[{ComputerName}]: PS C:\> Powershell -Version 2
Windows Powershell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserverd
```

And then it just hangs (or at least never lets me enter anything else into the console until I Ctrl-C).

I've also tried going through the Invoke-Command:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock { Powershell -version 2 }
```

and it does the same.

I've also tried to register a PSSessionConfiguration as per here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847899.aspx

```
PS C:\> Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name PS2 -PSVersion 2.0
```

But I get:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration: a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PSVersion'.
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what I can try next?!
Thanks

Comment: Whats in 2 that isn't in 3? Why is it easier? I'm honestly curious.

Comment: One what machine did you run `Register-PSSessionConfiguration`... your computer or the "server"? What is the OS of the server? I just tried the steps in the technet article and it worked perfectly. My 2008 server remoted to my windows 7 machine running a 2.0 PSSessionConfiguration. Have you tried this against a different server or host?

Comment: @RitchMelton - Alas SharePoint 2010 integration (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2796733)

Comment: @Matt - I tried running Register-PSSessionConfiguration on the 'other' computer and it worked perfectly, thanks heaps! :)

Comment: @Pete: I'm sorry. I'm also sad some things cant be unseen.

Comment: @Matt - You've answered his question.  If you put it in as an answer, he can mark it so, and we won't see this as unanswered.

Comment: @Matt, It's up to Pete to mark it answered now.  Or a moderator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On what machine did you run `Register-PSSessionConfiguration`?. Your computer or the "server"?

You need to make the configuration on the **target server**. That is what you will be running the hosted PSSessionConfiguration.

I just tried the steps in the [technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847899.aspx) and it worked perfectly. My 2008 server remoted to my windows 7 machine running a 2.0 PSSessionConfiguration.

On target server/host:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name PS2 -PSVersion 2.0
```

Then, on the client machine, reference the 'PS2' configuration.

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server01 -ConfigurationName PS2
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that the following doesn't work either:

```
 #Requires -version 2.0
```

Another kluge you could try is to create a scheduled task on the target and have the task fire off your script with `Powershell.exe -version 2`